# How to write two else condition in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

2 dictionary d1,d2, create a new dictionary with same keys.

```
d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1,'customer':'5'}
dict3 = { k: [ d1[k], d2[k] ] if k in d2 else [d1[k]] for k in d1 }
dict3
{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3']}
```

How to pass `else [d2[k]] for k in d2` to get the expected out

My Expected out

```
{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3'],'customer':['5']}
```

Disclaimer. I have done with `defaultdict`. Please give answer in `dict comprehension` only

Comment: `defaultdict` seems like a perfectly good way to do this- why do you want a comprehension?

Comment: `{ k: ([ d1[k], d2[k] ] if k in d2 else [d1[k]]) for k in d1 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a nested ternary `... if ... else (... if ... else ...)`, but what if there are three dictionaries, or four? 
Better use a nested list comprehension and iterate over the different dictionaries.

```
>>> d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
>>> d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1,'customer':'5'}
>>> {k: [d[k] for d in (d1, d2) if k in d] for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}
{'customer': ['5'], 'order': ['8', 1], 'product': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over both the dictionaries to include all the keys in new constructed dict.

You can achieve this by using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in d1.items():
    res[key].append(value)

for key, value in d2.items():
    res[key].append(value)
```

Output:

```
>>> dict(res)
>>> {'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3'], 'customer': ['5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `defaultdict` without a comprehension is a much, much better way to go, but as requested:

```
d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1,'customer':'5'}

d3 = {
    k: [d1[k], d2[k]]
    if (k in d1 and k in d2)
    else [d1[k]]
    if k in d1
    else [d2[k]]
    for k in list(d1.keys()) + list(d2.keys())
}
```

`d3` is now:

```
{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3'], 'customer': ['5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
>>> d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1, 'customer': '5'}

>>> dict3 = {k: [d1[k], d2[k]] if k in d1 and k in d2 else [d1[k]] if k in d1 else [d2[k]] for list in [d1, d2] for k in list}
>>> dict3
{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3'],'customer':['5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1, 'customer': '5'}
list_ = []
for i in [d1, d2]:
    list_.append(i)

list_
```

`[{'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'},
 {'order': 1, 'product': 1, 'customer': '5'}]`

```
dict_={}
for d in list_:
    for k,v in d.items():
        dict_.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
dict_
```

`{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3'], 'customer': ['5']}`

Comprehension

```
combined_key = {key for d in list_ for key in d}
combined_key
```

`{'customer', 'order', 'product', 'tracking'}`

```
super_dict = {key:[d[key] for d in list_ if key in d] for key in combined_key}
super_dict
```

`{'customer': ['5'], 'tracking': ['3'], 'order': ['8', 1], 'product': ['8', 1]}`